# Get All Weeks with start date and end date of given month (NSDate Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

i am trying to list all weeks of a given month
like
start date 6 sep 2020
end date 12 sep 2020

and if a week is ending in next month it should also display that date
like
start date 27 sep 2020
end date 3 oct 2020

a function which takes NSDate as input and returns array of dates (start and end date of the week) with NSArray or NSDictionary anything will work just needed start and end dates of given NSDate

i have tried DateTools, Datez and other pods but still not able to get this

```
    -(void) getWeeksOfTheMonthCurrent {
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *oneDayAgoComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    for(int currentdateindexpath=0;currentdateindexpath<=10currentdateindexpath++)
    {

        NSDateComponents* subcomponent = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitWeekday
                                                     fromDate:[NSDate date]];
        
        [oneDayAgoComponents setDay: 0 - ([subcomponent weekday] - 1)];
        
        NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents
                                                            toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
        NSString *weekstartdate = [formatter stringFromDate:beginningOfWeek];
        NSLog(@"weekstartdate %@",weekstartdate);

        
        NSDateComponents *components =
        [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth |
                              NSCalendarUnitDay) fromDate: beginningOfWeek];
        beginningOfWeek = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
        
        [oneDayAgoComponents setDay:7- ([subcomponent weekday])];
        
        NSDate *endOfWeek = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDayAgoComponents
                                                      toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yy"];
        NSString *weekendtdate = [formatter stringFromDate:endOfWeek];
        NSLog(@"weekendtdate %@",weekendtdate);
    }
    
    
}
```

i have tried this code for getting start week date and end week date but this is not what i want
i simply want a function which takes NSDate as parameter and returns a array of objects which contains start week date and end week date

Comment: Please show what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: i have updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use 3rd party libraries to do this, there are plenty of supplied date functions for this kind of thing (see mainly the documentation for `NSCalendar`).

This answer is in Swift, but I'll leave you to figure out the conversion.

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()

let monthInterval = calendar.dateInterval(of: .month, for: now)!

var weekIntervals: [DateInterval] = []
var startDate = monthInterval.start

while monthInterval.contains(startDate) {
    weekIntervals.append(calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, for: startDate)!)
    startDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: startDate)!    
}

// Not sure why this is needed, seems like the above should handle it
let finalWeek = calendar.dateInterval(of: .weekOfMonth, for: startDate)!
if finalWeek.start < monthInterval.end {
    weekIntervals.append(finalWeek)
}
```

Printing the results gives…

```
let formatter = DateIntervalFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
weekIntervals.forEach {
    print(formatter.string(from: $0)!)
}


// Jul 26, 2020, 12:00 AM – Aug 2, 2020, 12:00 AM
// Aug 2, 2020, 12:00 AM – Aug 9, 2020, 12:00 AM
// Aug 9, 2020, 12:00 AM – Aug 16, 2020, 12:00 AM
// Aug 16, 2020, 12:00 AM – Aug 23, 2020, 12:00 AM
// Aug 23, 2020, 12:00 AM – Aug 30, 2020, 12:00 AM
// Aug 30, 2020, 12:00 AM – Sep 6, 2020, 12:00 AM
```

Comment: thanks alot, but i solved my problem using NSDate Tools pod